# Steps for calling COM DLL API in my C# code

Tags: c#, dll, com-interop

I have got a native DLL that I wanted to use via COM in my .NET/C# project. I am a little confused on the steps to follow in order to use it in my C# project. Here is what I understand, please correct me wherever I am wrong.

1. Register COM DLL on the machine using regsvr32.
2. Somehow get the interop DLL(RCW)  from that native DLL. Not sure how to do that?
3. Add reference to interop DLL in .NET/C# project
4. Starting referencing calls from COM dll.

Comment: Step 3 takes care of step 2.  What is the real question?

Comment: Thanks @Hans. Just wanted to verify the steps as I have the native COM dll but don't see any Interop.XXX dll and I was confused how exactly to get that Interop.XXX dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a COM component (it has to be designed and compiled as such), you can add a COM reference using the Add Reference dialog; you will then have wrapper classes created for you.

If you are simply using a native DLL (not a COM component), you need to use `DllImport` to call native methods.

Comment: Thanks @Kieren. I am been told that this is a COM component. Is there any way of verifying it? Also in order to add reference to COM dll in C# project, can I just add that COM dll or will I need that interop.XXX dll ?